# convert data string from numpy array to int python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I have a string Numpy array in Python 3 like this [Numpy array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bn1hU.png),

```
array[['(155)'],['(255)'],['(165)'],['(147)']]
```

I need to convert this one to int Numpy array, like this,

```
array[[115],[255],[165],[147]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strip 'em and parse 'em:

```
np.core.defchararray.strip(a, '()').astype(int)
```

Comment: You can replace `np.core.defchararray` with `np.char`.

Comment: @AbhishekMishra: The NumPy documentation all uses `np.core.defchararray`, so I do too.